# Nuget Ignore content files copying twice

Tags: c#, nuget

I am trying to create a nuget package with the following structure:
content/Deploy.

Here is my sample nuspec file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package >
  <metadata>
    <id>$id$</id>
    <version>$version$</version>
    <title>$title$</title>
    <authors>$author$</authors>
    <owners>$author$</owners>
    <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
    <description></description>
    <copyright></copyright>
  </metadata>
     <files>
       <file src="$OutputPath$" target="content\Deploy" />
    </files>
</package>
```

So basically I copy everything from output directory into content\Deploy. The problem is that nuget pack is also generating lib directory and includes some content files from the project in content root directory. Is there a way to exclude everything except the files I specify?
The only content should be the content inside content/deploy in the generated nuget package. How to achieve that?